# python ttk treeview issues

Tags: python, treeview, ttk

I will be honest here and say that I'm playing with the treeviews and ttk without really understand how it works. Nevertheless, I'm getting some issues and after Googling for it I can't find a proper way to fix it. I use treeviews as listbox, since ttk doesn't have a listbox element.

- 1: Issue 1: somehow I got an extra column all the time, why?

  ```
  chat = ttk.Treeview(height="26", columns=("Nick","Mensaje","Hora"), selectmode="extended")
  chat.heading('#0', text='Nick', anchor=W)

  chat.heading('#1', text='Mensaje', anchor=W)

  chat.heading('#2', text='Hora', anchor=W)

  chat.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)

  chat.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=510)

  chat.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)

  chat.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, x=5, y=45)
  ```

But that adds an extra column at the end so i had to add to fix it:

```
chat.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
```

- Issue 2: While I'm trying to insert items to the `treeview`, I realized I can't find a way to say where the info should go. For example I want a variable to fill `column1` but another variable to fill `column2`. As far as I could go was:

  ```
  chat.insert('', "end", '', text=message)
  ```

But that would only add the message on the `column0`. How do i make it saves it on `column1` while another var is saved on `column0`?

- Issue 3: Is this really the best (easier, actually) way to display a listbox with ttk?

Thank you for your answers.

**Edit: i was tring to do something like this:** http://pdqi.com/w/Download/BLT/treeview1.gif or http://zoomq.qiniudn.com/ZQScrapBook/ZqFLOSS/data/20100928164510/multicolumn_treeview_plastiktheme.png

Answer (score 3):

*For issue 1*: I suggest you to rewrite your code:

```
chat = ttk.Treeview(height="26", columns=("Mensaje", "Hora"))

chat.heading('#0', text='Nick', anchor=W)
chat.heading('Mensaje', text='Mensaje', anchor=W)
chat.heading('Hora', text='Hora', anchor=W)

chat.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
chat.column('Mensaje', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=510)
chat.column('Hora', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
```

*For issue 2*: Use

```
chat.insert('', 'end', 'iid_1')
chat.set('iid_1', 'Hora', 'your value')
```

*For issue 3*: There is not presently a listbox in ttk, but you can use Listboxes from the classic Tk widgets.

Comment: oh... thanks! Then if that's how it works, would be possible to set the info of a column in an specific FontColour without affecting the entire row?

Comment: @Saelyth Probably, no.